# Unable to Connect to openfire server, no error or warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I a trying to connect to openfire server after following this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-setup--mobile-7190) and using the xmpp ios code sample.

the code is as follows

```
- (void)setupStream
{
NSLog(@"Setting up Stream");

xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[xmppStream setHostName:@"52.0.99.122"];
[xmppStream setHostPort:5222];

NSLog(@"Setup XMPP connection credentials");
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
{
    xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;
}
#endif

xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];

[xmppReconnect  activate:xmppStream];

[xmppStream addDelegate:self         delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

}

I want to know if there is a way to debug or atleast see some error messages.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you implemented 'connect' method?

Comment: Yes i did, the problem was in my Delegates i didn't use the Multicast delegate and thought that it was optional